# How can I read column variable from config file that's defined in my main file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pass a variable that's one of the columns I define in my config file:
config.py:

```
[REDSHIFT]
 columns: {file_name}, first_name, last_name
```

I define the file_name in my main python file.  I get this value from another location and need to load a table with this variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.